# Need example of mixed content in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have this HTML code:

```
<description>This is an <a href="example.htm">example</a> <it>text </it>!</description>
```

For this code, I have to create an XSD.

My try was to create an element with `xs:all` for `a` tag and `it` tag. But how can I create the simple text within the `xs:all`? I tried it with an string element, but this is of course wrong, because it is an element. But also if I am using an `any` element, it is an element. How can I create this simple text within the a and it tags?

```
<xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:complexType>
         <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="a">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" />
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="it" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow your `description` element to be a string with `a` and `it` elements mixed in zero or more times in any order:

- Use `mixed="true"` in XSD for [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).
- Use `xs:choice` with `minOccurs="0"` to allow `a` and `it`
  to never appear.
- Use `xs:choice` with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to allow `a` and `it`
  to appear multiple times.

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="description">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="a">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="it" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!