# Is having a scalar type and element inside a parent element bad design in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, design-decisions

We currently have the following structure as part of an API endpoint response.

```
<elements>
  <element arg1="" arg2="">id</element>
</element>
```

Now, I would like to add a sub-element to the element without changing the existing structure. This is what I had when adding the sub-element.

```
<elements>
  <element arg1="" arg2="">id
    <subelement arg1="" arg2="" />
  </element>
</element>
```

It seems like the easiest solution and as far as I read it's valid XML.
But is it bad design? Would the API users be able to handle this well in their languages (mostly C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your candidate design uses mixed-content for *data-oriented* XML.  You're right to suspect that it's non-ideal.  Users will not be able to leverage the benefits of markup to access `id` separately from `subelement`; parsing and XPath access would be harder than necessary.  If you're determined to use XML for data-oriented content, it would be better to have `id` wrapped in its own tag (or to use attributes for scalars -- see [XML Element vs XML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133755/290085)).

More broadly, realize that using XML for data-oriented content has been out-of-favor for good reasons for more than a decade.  New data-oriented APIs should not be based on XML. JSON is a commonly preferred alternative.

XML in general and mixed-content in particular are best used for *document-oriented* data.

### See also

- [Can an XML element have both text and element content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66148477/290085)
- [Need example of mixed content in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36990919/290085)
- [What is a markup language? (XML vs YAML vs JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69268625/290085)
- [XML vs JSON to represent database data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28241215/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Our API returns either json or XML based on the clients' request.
I wanted to add the subelement without changing the existing structure at all, but I think it would just be best to add the sub-elements' arguments to the element itself.